# SearchView UI component in Android 2.2

Tags: android-2.2-froyo, searchview

I want to know that if I can have a SearchView UI component in my app(that is in API level 8). The SearchView, in my knowledge was included from API level 11. Is there any component other that EditText with drawable of a search icon that I could possibly use in this context. I dont want any search api, Im planning to integrate my own functionality with this SearchView UI component. 
Thanks in advance

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SearchView provided by AppCompat: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) on how to integrate the Support Library into your project:

Comment: Thanks for the post. But I have used a drawable for this now. But I will try your suggestion sometime. Thanks for the effort once again.